# bc: decimal separator comma vs. point

Tags: bc

I like using bc in interactive mode as a calculator.
However, it only accepts the period (.) as decimal separator but I am using the a German keyboard layout, so I only have the comma (,) available on the numpad. This is quite inconvenient when using bc single handed on the numpad, because I have to move my hand and search for the period key when entering decimal fractions.

So I am looking for a simple way to use bc on the numpad only.

Some possibilities I see right now:

- Changing keyboard layout to English for bc
- Replacing comma with period during input
- Changing the decimal separator in bc

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: you could set a key binding in settings I think

Comment: @ravery: please be more specific

Comment: I knoow in setting you can put a key binding so that pressing a certian key does a specific action. you may also be able to remap the comma key on the number pad to type a period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is my alias as replacement for bc:

```
sh -c "sed -u 's/,/./g' | bc -l"
```

And this shortcut under my window manager:

```
urxvt -e sh -c "sed -u 's/,/./g' | bc -l"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

My variant, that doesn't break all the readline functions in bc:

```
alias bcl='xmodmap -e "keycode 91 mod2 = KP_Delete period"; bc -l; xmodmap -e "keycode 91 mod2 = KP_Delete comma"'
```

This remaps the keypad's Delete/Comma key to Delete/Period before starting bc, and maps it back to Comma after bc exits.